# Can i move status icons of gnome top bar to center of the bar?

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, indicator

Is there any way to move icons of installed extensions from right most of the panel to center along with weather and date.

Is there any way to do it with the help of dash to panel?
I tried to do so but it moves all the status icons of right to center but i only want to do it for some of them, like only icons of caffeine and clipboard manager in the attached picture.

[image]